# How can I amend my train timetable parsing code to account for trains that skip a particular station?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to find appropriate train departure times for an Android app - I'm using jsoup to connect to my local train timetable website (the timetables are given as simple tables, where a row represents a station, and a column represents a scheduled train) and capturing the row for a specific station.

[Here is an example of a row from the timetable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVz61.png)

My problem is that whoever made the table used three different types of notation to denote a train skipping the station: a "-" symbol, a " | " symbol, and an empty space. This is an issue because I am trying to sort through the array of train times, but I also want to keep track of how many trains are running through the day (given by the columns).

As I am separating the results of the array by a space, the end result will be unrepresentative of how many trains are running, as it simply skips the columns that hold empty spaces.

Here is the code I am using:

```
// jsoup method that captures the text in a row, and returns it as a string, with 
// the results separated by a space
Element departure = doc.getElementById("row_3");
deptext = departure.text();

// Split the large string into an array
String[] depList = deptext.split(" ");

for (int i=0; i < depList.length; i++) {
     if (arrList[i].equals("-"))
                    continue;
     else if (arrList[i].equals("|"))
                    continue;
     else {
        // do something
 }
```

How could I amend my code so that the array `deplist` will account for entries in the row that are populated by an empty space?

Comment: What if you did a replace of the '-', '|' and ' ' values to one single value e.g. '-' when you fetch the table. Then you can use empty spaces without the risk of ambiguity.

Comment: Your deptext would contain rows values separated by spaces, so would that mean a blank column (meaning skipping station) would have more than 1 spaces separating it?

Comment: @PopoFibo Oddly enough, no - for the example screenshot I provided, my `deptext` would read : - - 6:59 7:08 7:16 - - - - 7:25 7:31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find a little more information regarding the DOM that you're working with. However, making a couple of assumptions, I can at least answer in general terms.

```
deptext = departure.text();
```

provides a string, lacking white space for empty column entries. This is described, a little vaguely in the [JSoup API Docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) under Element.text() which states that this method :

> Gets the combined text of this element and all its children.

If there is no text in the empty elements of the row, then no text is returned as a placeholder. However, you can find the hints you need in the returned DOM.

For the sake of this example,let's assume that the document element returned here

```
Element departure = doc.getElementById("row_3");
```

Is a standard table row element, defined by the tr tag, and that the children of that element which contain the departure times are each table data, or td, html tags. Then, we can create `Elements` by using the following method of `Element`, called from `departure` :

```
Elements elements = departure.getElementsByTag("td");
```

You can then iterate through each departure element

```
for (Element element : elements) {
    if(element.hasText()) {
         // This element has more than whitespace in it
    } else {
         // This element is empty, or contains only whitespace
    }
}
```

In this way you will identify every td element which is a child of the element identified by 'row_3'. However, you will have to research the source of your html to determine which children of row_3 you really want to work with.

[Edit] As it turns out, the child elements of the element with id 'row_3' are div elements rather than td elements. In order to populate the Elements object with a selector on departure, use :

```
Elements elements = departure.getElementsByTag("div");
```

Comment: Thanks for this - however it seems like the rows are all contained as divs (with each individual train time within this row contained as a seperate div as well) within a single td element nested under a tr element. Sorry if this doesn't really make sense, not too well versed in web programming!

Comment: OK, that's fine, but the point remains the same. You get your row, and then iterate through the children elements of the row. It's really not very important if they are div children of a div child, or td children of a tr.
If you can give me the URL, or a sample of the HTML, I can help you identify the means to get through the DOM

Comment: Just tried the getElementsByTag() method with div instead, and it worked a charm - thank you!

Comment: Good work! Glad it worked out for you, I'll update the code above to reflect the option to use a div tag